# Is the Window ID returned by Chrome Extension window creation a WinAPI hWnd?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a tiny C program that makes window perist across browser navigation. I'm writing a Chrome Extension and would like a persistent window. The `alwaysOnTop` property of the window created by `chrome.windows.create` is bogus - it doesn't work (and that's a documented bug).

So, given that you can call native code from an Extension, I thought I'd write a trivial C routine that simply calls `setWindowPos()` and maybe also `setForegroundWindow()` to make this window truly be always on top. But, how to identify the window? And so I'm wondering whether the returned `id` property from `chrome.windows.create` is in fact a Windows `hWnd` - the window handle returned when you create a window using the Windows API (the code of which is in the `user32.dll`).

Does anyone know whether this is indeed the case? Sure would be nice if it were.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't make any assumptions on the value of `windowId`, other than that it's unique within a browser session. A simple test shows that the ID of the window is a positive integer, increased for each new tab, window, or (devtools) panel.

Comment: Most of the extension APIs are platform independent, I don't see why it would return a platform specific value ?

Comment: True. But even though the APIs may be platform independent, at some point they need to call functions at the OS level to make things happen. A Chrome Extension window is, after all, a Windows window (if running on Windows), and same for Mac. And that's why i was hoping there was some kind of correspondence between the ID and the hWnd. But as Rob W points out, it's probably unwise to make assumptions, and there's probably some intermediary windows manager at work - even before OS-level calls are made.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to get the hWnd?

Comment: This is a Chrome feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354597